# Is adding a more detailed, yet repetitive answer acceptable?

Tags: discussion, comments

I can not yet leave comments nor can I edit an answer; however, I would like to add a sentence or two of detail to a correct answer. Is adding a second, slightly more detailed, yet functionally repetitive answer acceptable?

If I should gain enough reputation to comment, it that the best way to add details to an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general it's better to improve existing answers than to add slightly different new ones. Everybody can edit answers, even anonymous users, so if you want to add some helpful details to an existing answer, please go ahead and do so. Your edit will then be put into a review queue accessible to higher-rep users and peer-reviewed.